# Flow issue with succeeding 'if' statements blocks on Jupiter Notebook

Tags: python, if-statement

I have [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13TP0buxPArig9T23BG4xoNV4Ogpi9Zxt/view?usp=sharing) which I've created via the Jupiter Notebook. It's a simple game of Blackjack. The first cells are used to create classes and functions. The last includes the game logic (which is also explained at the top level of the notebook document).

At the end of each round, the player is asked if it wants to play again. If not the game is over. If yes, it'll keep going in a loop until the player says no. The issue that I am encountering is that sometimes (and to my eyes, it seems random), at the end of a round, the player isn't asked if it wants to carry on playing but rather everything stops. I can't seem to understand why.

My take is that it seems that the issue lies with the flow, at the level of where the game logic comes together (last cell) where there are x2 blocks of "if" statements succeeding each other on the same indentation level within a while loop. Please help.

Reference:
`if player.value <= 21:`
etc
`if yes_no():`

Comment: Code must be in your post, not in external links.

Comment: thx RD, but the full code? I don't mind, but it's long.

Answer (score 0):

**Game Play**

To play a hand of Blackjack the following steps must be followed:

1. Create a deck of 52 cards
2. Shuffle the deck
3. Ask the Player for their bet
4. Make sure that the Player's bet does not exceed their available chips
5. Deal two cards to the Dealer and two cards to the Player
6. Show only one of the Dealer's cards, the other remains hidden
7. Show both of the Player's cards
8. Ask the Player if they wish to Hit, and take another card
9. If the Player's hand doesn't Bust (go over 21), ask if they'd like to Hit again.
10. If a Player Stands, play the Dealer's hand. The dealer will always Hit until the Dealer's value meets or exceeds 17
11. Determine the winner and adjust the Player's chips accordingly
12. Ask the Player if they'd like to play again

**Imports**

```
import random
from IPython.display import clear_output
```

(clear_output only available in Jupiter)

**Card values**

```
ranks = ('Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace')
suits = ('Hearts', 'Diamonds', 'Spades', 'Clubs')
values = {'Two':2, 'Three':3, 'Four':4, 'Five':5, 'Six':6, 'Seven':7, 'Eight':8, 
            'Nine':9, 'Ten':10, 'Jack':10, 'Queen':10, 'King':10, 'Ace':11}
```

**Classes**

```
class Card:
    
    def __init__(self,rank,suit):
        
        #create card attributes
        
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = values[rank]
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        #output card ID to user
        
        return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit


class Deck:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        #create a deck list and fill it with 52 cards
        
        self.all_cards = []
        
        for rank in ranks:
            for suit in suits:
                created_card = Card(rank,suit)
                self.all_cards.append(created_card)
        
    def shuffle(self):
        
        #shuffle cards
        
        random.shuffle(self.all_cards)
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        #print how many cards in the deck
        
        return f'This deck has {len(self.all_cards)} cards'
    
    def deal_one(self):
        
        return self.all_cards.pop()


class Hand:
    
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.hand = []
        self.value = 0
        self.aces = 0
    
    def add_one(self,card):
        
        self.hand.append(card)
        
        self.value += values[card.rank]
        
        if card.rank == 'Ace':
            self.aces += 1
    
    def adjust_aces(self):
        
        while self.value > 21 and self.aces:
            self.value -= 10
            self.aces -= 1


class PlayerPurse:
    
    def __init__(self,balance=0):

        self.balance = balance
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        #print purse balance
        
        return f"Player current balance: £{self.balance}"
        
    def win_bet(self,win):
        
        #deposit funds
        
        self.balance += win
        
        return f"Player current balance: £{self.balance}"
        
    def loose_bet(self,loose):
        
        #withdraw funds (but only if withdrawal amount is under or equal to the current balance)

        self.balance -= loose
        
        return f"Player current balance: £{self.balance}"
```

**Functions**

```
def show_hand(who,who1):
    
    hand_comp = ''
    
    for card in who.hand:
        hand_comp += " "+card.__str__()+","
        
    print(f"{who1}'s hand has:" + hand_comp[:-1], f"= {who.value}")


def yes_no():
    
    choice = 'wrong'

    while choice.lower()[0] not in ['y','n']:
        
        choice = input('Are you ready to play? Enter Yes or No.')
        
        if choice.lower()[0] not in ['y','n']:
            print('You did not enter the correct value. Enter Yes or No.')
    
    if choice.lower()[0] == 'y':
        return True
    
    else:
        return False


def hit():
    
    choice = 'wrong'

    while choice.lower()[0] not in ['y','n']:
        
        choice = input('Do you want to Hit? Enter Yes or No.')
        
        if choice.lower()[0] not in ['y','n']:
            print('You did not enter the correct value. Enter Yes or No.')
    
    if choice.lower()[0] == 'y':
        return True
    
    else:
        return False


def fund_purse():
    
    incorrect_choice = True
    
    while incorrect_choice:
        
        ask_purse = input('How much would you like to transfer to your betting purse?')

        #if player input is not a number
        while ask_purse.isdigit() == False or int(ask_purse) <= 0:
            print('Sorry, you did not enter the correct value. Try again!')
            break

        #fill up the Player's purse with the deposit
        if ask_purse.isdigit() == True and int(ask_purse) > 0:
            incorrect_choice = False
            return int(ask_purse)


def bet(who):
    
    incorrect_choice = True
    
    while incorrect_choice:
        
        ask_bet = input(f'Your current balance is: £{who.balance}\nHow much would you like to bet for your next hand?')

        #if player input is not a number or (is a number but negative or equal to 0)
        while (ask_bet.isdigit() == False) or (ask_bet.isdigit() == True and int(ask_bet) <= 0):
            print("You need to enter the correct value!")
            break

        if ask_bet.isdigit() == True:
            
            ask_bet = int(ask_bet)
        
            #if player bet is superior to its balance
            while ask_bet > who.balance:
                print(f"You can't bet over your current balance of {who.balance}")
                break

            #create pending bet, which will then be dealt with in diffreent manners when win/loose
            if ask_bet <= who.balance:
                return ask_bet
```

**Game Logic**

```
print('Hello and welcome to Blackjack')

ask1 = True

while ask1:
    
    ask1 = False
    #ask to play game
    if ask1 == yes_no():
        break
    
    else:
        #fund the purse
        clear_output()
        player_bank = PlayerPurse(fund_purse())
        ask2 = True
        
    while ask2:
        
        game_on = True
        
        while game_on:

            #create a new deck
            game_deck = Deck()

            #shuffle the new deck
            game_deck.shuffle()

            #reset pending bet
            pending_bet = 0

            #ask player for their bet
            clear_output()
            pending_bet = bet(player_bank)

            #create hands for the Dealer & Player
            dealer = Hand()
            player = Hand()

            #deal two cards to the Dealer & Player
            dealer.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())
            player.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())
            dealer.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())
            player.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())

            #show one of the dealer's top card
            clear_output()
            print(f"Dealer first card: {dealer.hand[0]}")

            #show player's hand
            show_hand(player,"Player")
            player.adjust_aces()

            #ask the Player if they wish to Hit, and take another card
            while player.value <= 21:
                
                if hit() == True:
                    clear_output()
                    player.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())
                    player.adjust_aces()
                    print(f"Dealer first card: {dealer.hand[0]}")
                    show_hand(player,"Player")
                
                else:
                    break

            #if the player done hitting and not bust, dealer's turn
            if player.value <= 21:

                #dealer to hit given the established conditions
                while dealer.value < 17 or dealer.value < player.value:
                    clear_output()
                    dealer.add_one(game_deck.deal_one())
                    dealer.adjust_aces()
                    show_hand(dealer,"Dealer")
                    show_hand(player,"Player")

                #when dealer goes bust
                if dealer.value > 21 or dealer.value < player.value:
                    clear_output()
                    pending_bet = pending_bet*2
                    player_bank.win_bet(pending_bet)
                    show_hand(dealer,"Dealer")
                    show_hand(player,"Player")
                    print(f'Player wins £{pending_bet}. Player balance is now £{player_bank.balance}')

                #when dealer wins
                elif dealer.value > player.value:
                    clear_output()
                    player_bank.loose_bet(pending_bet)
                    show_hand(dealer,"Dealer")
                    show_hand(player,"Player")
                    print(f'Dealer wins £{pending_bet}. Player balance is now £{player_bank.balance}')

                #push
                else:
                    clear_output()
                    show_hand(dealer,"Dealer")
                    show_hand(player,"Player")
                    print(f"It's a tie. The £{pending_bet} bet goes back to the Player who's balance is now £{player_bank.balance}")

            #if the player goes bust after hitting
            else:
                clear_output()
                player_bank.loose_bet(pending_bet)
                show_hand(dealer,"Dealer")
                show_hand(player,"Player")
                print(f'Busted. Dealer wins £{pending_bet}. Player balance is now £{player_bank.balance}')

            #ask if want to play again
           
                ask2 = True
                break
            else:
                ask1 = False
                ask2 = False
                game_on = False
                break
        
print('Thanks for playing. Bye now!')
```